# avro 1.8.2 date type and writing as parquet

Tags: avro, parquet

Am using avro 1.8.2 and a simple avro idl record like so

```
record FooRecord {
       string fooString;
       int fooInt;
       union {null, date} fooDate = null;
}
```

fails to be written to parquet. From some of the solutions I have seen they recommend moving to avro 1.9 (but I probably don't want to do that because most of our current tech-stack uses 1.8.2).

Is there some way to make this work with avro-1.8.2 ?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.joda.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValueWithoutConversion(AvroWriteSupport.java:323)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValue(AvroWriteSupport.java:275)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeRecordFields(AvroWriteSupport.java:191)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.write(AvroWriteSupport.java:165)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:128)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:299)
```

Comment: What tools/commands are you using for this?

Comment: simple java code

Answer (score 1):

Logical Data types time support will need to be added

```
    GenericData timeSupport = new GenericData();
    // need to add logicalTime Support
    timeSupport.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.DateConversion());
    timeSupport.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimeConversion());
    timeSupport.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
    ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> avroParquetWriter = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord> builder(parquetPath)
                                                                      .withSchema(avro.getSchema())
                                                                      .withDataModel(timeSupport)
                                                                      .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                                                                      .build();
```